# How to perform a MySQL Query with 3 tables? One of the tables has foreign keys in the other two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
Message:
MessageID, SubscriptionID, UserID (Sender), title, text

Subscription:
SubscriptionID, UserID (Receiver)

User:
UserID, firstname, lastname
```

I want to have the following result:

```
firstname (Sender), lastname (Sender), firstname (Receiver), lastname (Receiver), title, text
```

Can anyone help me?
I tried several SQL Queries but none of them worked

I found a solution (Aurels solution is better):

```
SELECT User.firstname, User.lastname, tmp.firstname, tmp.lastname, title, text
FROM Message, User,
     (SELECT SubscriptionID, firstname, lastname 
      FROM User, Subscription 
      WHERE User.UserID=Subscription.UserID) AS tmp
WHERE Message.UserID=User.UserID AND Subscription.SubscriptionID=tmp.SubscriptionID
```

Comment: I just solved it. I will add the solution to the question later for everyone

Comment: Of course you have when @Aurel helped...

Comment: No, I saw his answer after I had solved this

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer you found by yourself. 
The "," style is the old way equivalent to INNER JOIN. but INNER JOIN is more readable (for me) as we know how you wanted to join your table. 
In the same way, with INNER JOIN or other JOIN types, you can separate filters in Where clause, and join conditions in ON clauses.

And i think we should avoid subquery everytime it's possible, for performances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this.
Your difficulty : the same table is involved twice in your query, with different roles (Receiver and Sender). The second time it is involved you also need a join on Subscription table.

So for your second call, you need to alias your table and so not confusing them.

We can discussed for type of join (left outer, inner), but as i have no more context, i decided to query all messages first, and guessing some messages shouldn't have one receiver or one sender (malformed)

```
Select User.firstname as 'firstname (Sender)', User.lastname as 'lastname (Sender)', Receiver.firstname as 'firstname (Receiver)', Receiver.lastname as 'lastname (Receiver)', Message.title, Message.text
from Message left outer join User on User.UserID = Message.UserID
left outer join Subscription on Subscription.SubscriptionID = Message.SubscriptionID
left outer join User as Receiver on Receiver.UserID = Subscription.UserID
```

Comment: I just solved it. I will add the solution to the question later for everyone

Comment: @Grevak so if the only difference is join type or alias name, please accept my answer if it works.

Comment: The difference is that I used FROM with comma seperated tables and one of the tables is a subquery

Comment: @Grevak that is not a good way. Share it with us - add it in the question. This way is better (the way Aurel did it...)

Comment: I shared my solution

Comment: Hi @Grevak I stay at what I have written before: the solution from Aurel is better.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try something like this. 
You need 2 joins to the User table.
The first to get the **Sender** and the second to get the **Receivers** information.

```
Select           Sender.firstname as SenderFirstName,
                 Sender.lastname as SenderLastName,
                 Receiver.firstname as RecieverFirstName,
                 Receiver.lastname as RecieverLastName,
                 Message.title,
                 Message.text
From             Message 
join             Subscription on Subscription.SubscriptionID = Message.SubscriptionID
left join        User as Receiver on Receiver.UserID = Subscription.UserID
left join        User as Sender on Sender Sender.UserID = Message.UserID
```

Comment: Please can you tell me what is the difference between this and answer from @Aurel ?

Comment: @VBoka They are the same. Not sure if they were posted very close in time to each. I posted my answer probably just after his solution. I hope you find my code more readable. ;)

Comment: The code is maybe more readable but the other answer was faster more than 15 min and it has some good pointers in the explanation part...